Can I change the Windows key shortcuts in Windows 11?
I want to use the key combo Windows+E for a certain shortcut in an application (IntelliJ), but the Windows operating system is using it to mean "open file explorer". How can I change those Windows key shortcuts? I don't need that shortcut for opening the file explorer. So I could get rid of it entirely, or use something like Windows+Control+E. Then Windows+E would be free to use in the IntelliJ keymap editor.

Out of curiosity... rather than trying to fight the OS - why not use Windows+Control+E for IntelliJ ? You can define your own shortcuts https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts.html

Because I use the IntelliJ command a ton, and the Windows command very little. The 2-key is easier than the 3-key, and I have muscle memory for the command (Meta-E / Apple-E) from other platforms. If Windows has no way to customize those bindings, so be it, I'll have to change up my key bindings and retrain myself.
